# Visual Studio 2017 does not generate any warnings if the variables are uninitialized?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, initialization, clang, warnings

The problem with Visual Studio and warnings when the variables are uninitialized

I have tried another compiler like Clang. The Clang was able to generate warnings.

```
//clang 3.8.0
//MSVS 2017
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class dummy
{
public:
    void dummyFunction()
   {
        static_cast<int>(m_DummyVariable);
   }
private:
    double m_DummyVariable;
};

int main()
{
    dummy obj;
    double outside;
    static_cast<int>(outside);
    obj.dummyFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

I expected to get three warnings as the online clang was able to do so. However, in Visual Studio regardless of the warning level(1,2,3,4 or all warnings options) which I have set in project's properties, I have not been able to get any warnings. Do I have to change any property of my project?

Comment: What is the compile command you used? I seem to recall Visual Studio uses `/W3` by default.

Comment: Most warnings that compilers can emit are _not_ required by the standard.  So I am wondering why you are **expecting** to get three warnings from Microsoft's CL.EXE compiler/linker.

Comment: do you get warnings when you actually use the uninitialized values? I mean a value being not initialized by itself isnt really the problem

Comment: Note that clang 3.8 only has 1 warning about an uninitialized variable being used. The other two are the results of `static_cast` being discarded. I can't find a version of clang that can complain about the uninitialized member in `dummyFunction`. Unsurprising really.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the member is default initialized, no?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Yes it is, which for a `double` means leaving it uninitialized.

Comment: fwiw [1 warning for `outside` being used uninitialized and 2 warning for discarding the casted values](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bt0yGY2ms7KRVj0t). Please be more explicit about what warnings you expect

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux oh, i can never remember the rules and warning are not reliable, the easiest is to initialize everything explicitly

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Both of the static casts are formally undefined behaviour (as they involve evaluating an uninitialized variable).  However most compilers won't spot that until they crank up the optimization level - at which point they may well discard the whole expression because there are no side effects.

Comment: What types of warnings you can provide depends a lot on the compiler's internals in addition to how many (and which) developers you have and how you prioritise. You can't expect all compilers to have the same "extra special not-required-but-helpful" features.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on you project and hit properties, go to the bottom and click on Code Analysis. Changing rule set to Microsoft All Rules as well as ticking the box to run code analysis on build makes warnings appear for me.
Worth noting that as soon as I send the outside variable to standard output Visual Studio throws a warning and an error.